# Retrieve command output to variable when command has spaces

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command

I've read in various places that I can use Windows batch file `for` to grab the output of a command and put it in a variable, like this:

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('foo-command') DO SET FOO=%%G
```

Great. So my `foo-command` is actually `C:\Program Files\Foo\foo.bat`, and this is stored in the `FOO_BAT` variable. And it takes a parameter `bar` with value `blah blah='foobar' blah`. So I try that:

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('%FOO_BAT% -bar "blah blah='foobar' blah"') DO SET FOO=%%G
```

I get a lovely `'C:\Program' is not recognized...`. Nothing I can do can get around the space in the command.

If you want to reproduce this, create a simple `C:\Program Files\Foo\foo.bat` file containing just the following, and then run the line above in a batch file.

```
echo FooBar
```

**How can I capture the output of a command (which takes parameters) as a Windows batch variable, if the command has spaces in its path?**

- Yes, I've tried putting quotes around `%FOO_EXE%`.
- Yes, I've tried putting everything in a separate variable and using that single variable in the `FOR`.
- Please try this *with the parameters I supplied* before telling me it works. The presence of the parameters changes everything.

Comment: You need quotes around your "%FOO_EXE%" variable.

Comment: @Squashman I guess you missed the part where I said "Yes, I've tried putting quotes around `%FOO_EXE%`".

Comment: Edit your original question and put the exact usage you tried when using QUOTES around the executable.  There is a space after the word program, so that is a dead giveaway that you did not use the quotes correctly based on the ERROR you provided.

Comment: @Squashman please try `FOR /F %%G IN ('"C:\Program Files\Foo\foo-command.exe" -bar "blah blah='foobar' blah"') DO SET FOO=%%G` yourself and then tell me what you get as an error. Thanks.

Comment: @Squashman I'm very interested in the error you received when you run the command above. Could you just post it here for all of us? Thanks.

Comment: foo-command.exe is does not exist in that path which is why you are getting that error.  Just tested this with one of my programs.  When I changed the name of the executable, then I received the same error as you.

Comment: @Squashman, you're beating around the bush with the red herring that `foo-command.exe` does not exist (I already noted that the error message indicates the the wrong path is being used), and your command is irrelevant because you're not using the same parameters that I gave. So here is a simple way to settle this: create a `C:\Program Files\Foo\foo.bat` file (I've updated the question with this) and try _exactly_ the `FOR` command in the example. It won't work. Prove me wrong and I will be grateful. But try it before you talk about "dead giveaways" please.

Comment: SFK does use parameters and I did try your code.  I just didn't use parameters in my example.

Comment: @Squashman You didn't try _my_ parameters!!! Come on. Just once. Create the batch files above and just run them _with my parameters_! And tell me what you get.

Comment: I don't need to. I can do the same thing with SFK.

Comment: None of your examples are using the back tick as Jason has suggested you use.

Comment: (sigh) But you'll see that adding the parameters makes it all break. The fact that won't try it and post your results is a "dead giveaway" (to use your words) that you're afraid that you'll come up with the same results I do, which would be embarrassing after you were so critical in your original comments. (And it doesn't matter whether I use back ticks or single quotes or whatever.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('CALL "C:\path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah"') do set foo=%%G
```

Give this a try. And yes I tested it.  Foo.bat does nothing more then just echo %1.

Comment: Good idea! I didn't even think to use `CALL`. I believe it works the same on a non-batch (in his case EXE) file as well.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, I did not want to get scolded again for using my SFK.exe as an example.  I like your short file name example.

Comment: @Squashman, that did the trick! Hooray!! `FOR` seems to be really finicky with spaces in the "command" if there are complicated parameters. Using `CALL` as the "command" got around that. Thank you so much! I'm going to add a bounty so I can award it to this answer.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I wound up not testing your answer, as this one worked and was much shorter. But yours certainly looks like a clever trick. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: @GarretWilson, while it may be shorter then Jason's script, his may actually run faster.  There is always a small overhead with using CALL. Slows down the script a fraction. In this instance it may not be that significant but use CALL in a large LOOP could be a significant time difference.

Comment: @GarretWilson - I agree that this solution is the more straightforward (better) solution. Clever may have it's place, but simplicity is almost always better.

Comment: OK, clever peeps. Here's one last gotcha. How do I get the `ERRORLEVEL` back? This format creates another command instance, so I always get `0` for `ERRORLEVEL`, even if `foo.bat` resulted in an error.

Comment: @GarretWilson, I would start a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you are trying to process output directly from a `FOR` loop, I would recommend including the `usebackq` parameter. This allows you to include quotes in your command (as is often needed) to specify full file paths or individual parameters which have spaces in them.

For example:

```
REM Using the DIR command with FOR switches, extract the short name.
REM The path specified below can be fed by a variable.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN (`DIR "C:\Program Files\Foo\foo-command.exe" /B /S`) DO SET FooPathShortName=%%~sG
ECHO Short Name is: %FooPathShortName%

REM No quotes are needed to run the short name.
FOR /F "usebackq" %%G IN (`%FooPathShortName% -bar "blah blah='foobar' blah"`) DO SET Foo=%%G
```

In the above, I am using the `DIR` command to output the full path of the target executable into a format which the `FOR` function can parse as a file. From this I am determining the short name of the file which does not require spaces to execute in the second `FOR` command.

Comment: Jason, did you test that theory.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I've read the help. But the following still does not work: `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%G IN (\`"C:\Program Files\Foo\foo-command.exe" -bar "blah blah='foobar' blah"\`) DO SET FOO=%%G`. Seriously, just copy and paste, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @GarretWilson - My command was just an example, I've updated it to more accurately reflect what you are trying to do. Note the comment I added as well. What is the raw output of the command itself (if you don't process in the `FOR` loop)? This might add some clarity.

Comment: Like I said @JasonFaulkner, copy and paste and you'll see for yourself! Why don't you run the command you gave me yourself? Yes, I know you don't have a `foo-command.exe` on your machine, but the error message will indicate that Windows thinks the command is `'C:\Program'` and not `'C:\Program Files\Foo\foo-command.exe'`. Have you tried to run the batch file you gave me in your answer?

Comment: @GarretWilson - Yes, I just tried it with 2 quoted parameters (obviously a different tool) and it seems to work for me. I am curious what this isn't working for you... what version of Windows do you have (I have 7)? A workaround you can do is to temporarily append the `PATH` so you don't have to quote the command. See updated answer.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, test it with any executable.  If you use the **usebackq** option and single quote the double quoted executable path, all you will get is the path back as your token variable.  It does not execute the command.  In my case I tested with this: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %G IN ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\SFK\sfk.exe"') do echo %G` and my output was this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SFK\sfk.exe"`

Comment: @Squashman - You are using single quotes `'`, not the backtick char `.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, this works `FOR /F "delims=" %G IN ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\SFK\sfk.exe"') do echo %G` the same as this: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %G IN (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\SFK\sfk.exe"`) do echo %G` Not understanding when you would use one and not the other.  They both produce the same output.  The web software is removing my backticks in the command/

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, setting the `PATH` is cheating and won't fix my problem. And what you do with `sfk.exe` is not addressing my issue, because it doesn't use parameters. So do this simple test, like I asked Squashman: create a `C:\Program Files\Foo\foo.bat` file and show me a `FOR` command that will work _with the parameters I gave_.

Comment: @Squashman - In most cases it doesn't matter. However, I often run SQL commands from the command line which use the `'` char to escape strings. Without the `usebackq` option, I wouldn't be able to do that. However, typically you never use the backtick in an actual command, so it is generally "safer" to turn this option on.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @GarretWilson - Sorry for the frustration. Is your `'foo-command'` in the line `FOR /F %%G IN ('foo-command') DO SET FOO=%%G` _always_ a path? If so we can do a workaround with the path variable (I would need to update the answer). I just need that clarification.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, as I mention above, yes, `%FOO_BAT% (see updated question) must be a path with spaces, and updating the _PATH_ is cheating in my use case. Please see my updated question; if you duplicate it exactly (just two minutes with a text editor) you should get the exact same results I do. The parameters break everything.

Comment: @GarretWilson - I am proposing to convert it to a short name and using that to execute. I assume that the answer to my question is 'yes', a path is always provided - this being the case, I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @GarretWilson - See updated answer. This converts to the short name and executes based off of that. You don't have to quote the short name so  this would, seemingly, get you around your issue.

Comment: Ooh, that looks clever. I have to suspend work on this until probably tomorrow, but I'll try this as soon as possible. Thanks. It looks promising.

Comment: @GarretWilson - Glad to help. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner you could shorten that to: `FOR %%G IN ("C:\Program Files\Foo\foo-command.exe") do SET FooPathShortName=%%~sG`

Comment: @Squashman - I tried that initially but I couldn't get the `FOR` command to apply the file manipulation functions which is why I wrapped it in a `DIR` call. Overall, the solution got too cute for it's own good - yours is much simpler and a better fit for the problem at hand.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, I tried to award some of my 50 bounty to you because of the work you put into this, but I had forgotten I couldn't split up the value. Next time I'll remember and assign two bounties if I want to distribute it. Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @GarretWilson - Thanks for the thought! No worries at all though - I'm glad you got your issue resolved.